# javax.ws.rs.core.Response$Status.getReasonPhrase() Issue on JAXB, Rest service Implementation using Apache Jersey

Tags: web-services, apache, rest, jakarta-ee, jax-rs

I am facing below issue while trying to access the below **REST** service...
I am using Apache Jersey implementation for developing rest service.

I am facing below issue only when i am trying JAXB, ie..., using to produce response tye as JSON.

Below are the list of JAR i am using.

```
jersey-bundle_1.0.0.0_1-1-5-1.jar
jsr311-api-1.0.jar
jackson-core-asl_1.0.0.0_1-1-1.jar
jettison_1.0.0.0_1-1.jar
```

Below is the exception trace...

```
Problem accessing /service/calender/testRest. Reason:


javax.ws.rs.core.Response$Status.getReasonPhrase()Ljava/lang/String;
Caused by:

java.lang.

NoSuchMethodError: javax.ws.rs.core.Response$Status.getReasonPhrase()Ljava/lang/String;
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponse.traceException(ContainerResponse.java:477)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponse.onException(ContainerResponse.java:452)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponse.mapWebApplicationException(ContainerResponse.java:407)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1036)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:941)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:932)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:384)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:451)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:632)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
```

My web.xml

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Calender</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name>
        <param-value>com.punith.calender.application.CalenderApp</param-value>
    </init-param>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Calender</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/service/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

and My Handler..

```
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Path("/testRest")
public TestObject testJson() {
    TestObject testObj = new TestObject("test", "value");
    return testObj;
    /*return "Hello World";*/
}
```

My TestObject class..

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
@XmlRootElement(name="testObject")

public class TestObject {
    public String name;
    public String value;


    public TestObject(String objName, String objValue) {
        this.name = objName;
        this.value = objValue;
    }
```

I highly doubt on the jars used and guess i have to use more jar for the JAXB.. Incase please let me know the link to download the JAR...

Regards
Puntih

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are the below jar needs to be used..

Jersey bundle

```
jersey-bundle-1.17.jar
```

and For JAXB below are the JAR

```
jaxb-api.jar
jaxb-impl-javadoc.jar
jaxb-impl.jar
jaxb-xjc-javadoc.jar
jaxb-xjc.jar
```

Solved... thanks